# Getting different viewport height in different browser tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

How the viewport size is getting determined?

I have designed two html pages with similar layout, but still I am getting different viewport heights & same view port widths for them.

I am using

```
$(window).height()
$(window).width()
```

function to find the size of viewport.

Comment: When you're calculating them, is your developer tools open? That might be one case in which height is different but same width

Comment: @AbhinavSingi Yes, the developers tools are open in both the cases. But the difference in value is huge. For one I am getting 2460 and for other 659.